# Perform rearrangement of fields in an RDD-spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of type

> rdd[(String,String,String)] // this refers to a record of format
>   (devicename,date,text)

Now I need to perform groupbyKey of (devicename,date). So I thought to transform the

> rdd[(String,String,String)] to rdd[(String,String),String)]

but I am unable to transfer. I had tried to use

```
val namedatekeyrecord=ip.map{

x =>

(a,b,c)=>((a,b),c)

}
```

but it does not work and throws error "missing parameter type".

Could you help me in my approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,

I forgot to use map abstractions:

```
val namedatekeyrecord=ip.map{

x =>

((x._1,x._2),x._3)

}
```